# Json.net not compatible for windows phone 8.1

Tags: json.net, windows-phone-8.1

Trying to add NewtonSofts json.net library via nuget. Getting a "not compatible" dialog when clicking install.

1...Create new "Blank App" for Windows Phone 8.1 project in Visual Studio 2013 update 2
2...Click Manage NuGet packages
3...Find json.net version 6.0.3
4...Error dialog saying not compatible

Dialog also lists compatible versions, which includes wp7, wp80 and something called wpa81.

The error i get is as follows:

```
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3'.
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3' to App1.
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: Also found that the console manager also fails and does provide clear feedback that wp81 is not supported. Will contact json.net...

Comment: I just tested it and was able to add Json.NET to a blank WP8.1 project (both Silverlight and WinRT).

Comment: why not use Windows.Data.Jason library it is the default library with windows phone.

Comment: 8.1 Silverlight or XAML ?

Comment: Problem with both 8.1 silverlight and 8.1 Phone. I have the same problem with the HTTP Client Libraries which also claim to be WP8.1 compatible. I'm in the process of trying this on a colleagues PC.

Comment: Just to update anyone looking at this, I've tried this on a clean VM and it does work, so something wrong on my PC somewhere. Its funny because a colleage is getting exactly the same problem. Hopefully provide an explanation shortly...

Comment: I am also getting this error using NuGet in Visual Studio 2013 trying to install the google API, as it relies on it, I get the following error: Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: I've still been struggling with this 6 months on! I ended up re-installing VS2013 Update 3, and the problem still occurred. However, once I'd updated the Nuget Manager Add-In, it worked :-). I think this proves that there was a bug somewhere that is now resolved in the new version of the Nuget Manager.

Comment: OK, its just happened again with HttpClientExtensions. However, i managed to get it to work by installing Json.net first, then HttpClient, then HttpClientExtensions. Clearly a problem still exists in NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today as well. To fix it, here's a silly one, I unchecked WP8.1 on my project, installed JSON.NET, then went in and passive aggressively rechecked it, but it worked! On two separate projects, I might add. I built, deployed, tested, and all that good stuff without issue after that. I have no idea why, but I'm pretty sure as experienced developers we've all learned never to question things that work.